# mongodb - can i write to the database while sharding?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I know this may sounds like a naive question, but I don't seem to see much on google. Is it ok to insert / upsert documents into a mongodb (3.6) database, while sharding is going on (i.e. the chunk balancer is running)? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/concurrency/#how-does-sharding-affect-concurrency) is pretty clear on this:

> Sharding improves concurrency by distributing collections over
>   multiple mongod instances, allowing shard servers (i.e. mongos
>   processes) to perform any number of operations concurrently to the
>   various downstream mongod instances.
>
> In a sharded cluster, locks apply to each individual shard, not to the
>   whole cluster; i.e. each mongod instance is independent of the others
>   in the sharded cluster and uses its own locks. The operations on one
>   mongod instance do not block the operations on any others.

So, yes, you can run any query against a cluster at any time. This should be completely transparent to your client and MongoDB will internally manage potentially required locks.